# What's the meaning of expiry timeout in Activemq PooledConnectionFactory?

Tags: timeout, jms, activemq-classic

I don't understand the application of expiryTimeout field in Activemq  PooledConnectionFactory. The java doc said "allow connections to expire, irrespective of load or idle time. This is useful with failover to force a reconnect from the pool, to reestablish load balancing or use of the master post recovery". please give me an example, a real scenario which expiryTimeout field effect in it.

Answer (score 1):

The expiry timeout option is a bit of a legacy feature of the Pool that isn't all that useful in most applications these days.  The way it works is that if you configure an expiration time then the Connection that is loaned out and is later closed will be completely closed and dropped should there be no other active users of the Connection, otherwise it stays alive until all active instances are closed, then the underlying Connection object is closed.

This works slightly differently than the Idle timeout which applies to Connection instances that are sitting unused in the pool and are closed after some length of time to release resources on the Broker side.

These days you are better off using a failover URI in the PooledConnectionFactory with broker support for rebalance of cluster clients enabled which would then dynamically redistribute the load in the broker cluster as opposed to the expiry timeout which only closes down Connection instances once everyone that is currently actively using them has released them by calling close on them.